# Why does GHCi not show the same error message as GHC

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghc, ghci

Reasoning about an error given in [Haskell type error on compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886961) I found a strange behaviour of GHCi

### `test.hs`

```
members :: String -> Bool;
members str = and [ b | x <- str, b <- map (elem x) "abcde" ]
```

produces the following error message

```
Prelude> :l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
```

> ```
> test.hs:2:53: error:
>     • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘t0 Char’
>       Expected type: [t0 Char]
>         Actual type: [Char]
>     • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘"abcde"’
>       In the expression: map (elem x) "abcde"
>       In a stmt of a list comprehension: b <- map (elem x) "abcde"
> ```

whereas

### `GHCi`

```
Prelude> members :: String -> Bool; members xs = and [ b | x <- xs, b <- map (elem x) "abcde"]
```

produces

> ```
> <interactive>:18:78: error:
>     • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
>       Expected type: [[Char]]
>         Actual type: [Char]
>     • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘"abcde"’
>       In the expression: map (elem x) "abcde"
>       In a stmt of a list comprehension: b <- map (elem x) "abcde"
> ```

### Update

What I also do not understand, is why GHC omits the `Foldable t0` class constraint - I
would have expected the error message be something like:

> ```
> test.hs:2:53: error:
>     • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘t0 Char’
>       Expected type: Foldable t0 => [t0 Char]
>         Actual type: [Char]
>     • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘"abcde"’
>       In the expression: map (elem x) "abcde"
>       In a stmt of a list comprehension: b <- map (elem x) "abcde"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Introduced by the FTP (Foldable-Traversable-Proposal) function `elem` has
gotten a new type signature.

```
elem :: (Eq a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

And it seems GHCi uses the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension which can be deactivated by

```
:set -NoExtendedDefaultRules
```

This extension and [trac:10971](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10971) makes `Foldable` and
`Traversable` default to `[]`.

### update

The class constraint is not shown, because the type checking for it is done at a later stage.

Comment: The constraint is omitted since it not checked at that point, I guess. We have a `Char` where we expect a `t Char`. It's similar to the error message if you define `equal :: a -> b -> Bool; equal x y = x == y`. Only if you fix the `b` to `a` you get the missing `Eq` instance error, but before that the (unconstrained) type of `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool` already stops us from type-checking the `equal` variant above.

Comment: thought sthg in the line of that, but wasn't sure!

Comment: TBH, one would have to check GHC's type-checking code. I guess TC comes before instance check. But that _may_ be an interesting follow-up question (as long as it's on-topic).

Comment: I guess that is a question a bit too broad - but I'll write one after work ;-)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17710234)

Comment: @Shoe - I updated both the question and the answer to be more complete.